# Skip before_filter defined with block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, before-filter

Is it possible to skip a before filter in using `skip_before_filter` when the before_filter is defined with a block. For example:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter do |controller|
    # filter stuff
  end
end
```

I know, that is it possible using the "normal" way of defining the filter with a method name.

Comment: do not think so, move it to a method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its most definitely not possible.  From the documentation:

> Note that skipping uses Ruby equality, so it’s impossible to skip a callback defined using an anonymous proc using #skip_filter

http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods/skip_action_callback

Answer (score 3):

I actually found a way around this using an if option with a method. Use

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter(:if => :use_filter?) do |controller|
    # filter stuff
  end

  private

  def use_filter?
    true
  end
end

class OtherController < ApplicationController
  private

  def use_filter?
    false
  end
end
```

:D

Comment: Or you can use :unless => inherited_controller?

  def inherited_controller?
    self.class != ApplicationController
  end