# skip around_filter with argument & block rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, action, skip

There is an around_filter defined in application_controller.rb. It takes a string argument and the block. This is applicable for almost all controller methods except for few. However am unable to skip it for the unwanted actions. Code snippet below.

case 1:

```
around_action {|controller, block| controller.send(:my_around_action, request.host, block)}
```

In the controller where this filter needs to be skipped, I put

```
skip_filter :my_around_action
```

However this doesn't work.

If I redefine around_action as below, everything works as excepted.

case 2:

```
around_action :my_around_action
```

Running below command returns results for respective cases

```
ApplicationController._process_action_callbacks.map {|c| c.filter if c.kind == :around}.compact
```

case 1 :

> [:my_around_action]

case 2 :
[]

Comment: Just now found out that even the before_action can't be skipped if it has a proc. Is there any way to skip such filters?

Comment: Okay, found out from [another thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19021465/skip-before-filter-defined-with-block) that there is no straight forward way to skip it.